# Angular: "Passing" ng-template to a third party component

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

A third party component, let's say `p-table` expecting an `ng-template` in itself (with a directive, `pTemplate="header"` for example). Like:

```
<p-table>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">...USEFULL STUFF...</ng-template>
    ...
<p-table>
```

My question is, how can I "pass" to the `p-table` an `ng-template`, that is somewhere else (the directive and optional input parameters should work)? For example:

```
<p-table>
    <!-- This isn't working: -->
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="myHeader">...</ng-template>
    ...
<p-table>

<ng-template #myHeader pTemplate="header">...USEFULL STUFF...</ng-template>
```

The point is I don't want to put the `ng-template` with `pTemplate` directly inside the `p-table` element. I want to code it somewhere else (outside of it, for some reasons), but I want it somehow to pass/inject/transfer/etc to the `p-table`, so it can use it normally. `p-table` shouldn't even know that there is a 'hacking'.

Comment: i am not quite sure but you can make use of services that might help or event input or outputbinding

Comment: Does this library not have usage examples? Generally you'd just put regular markup inside the element; `ng-template` will then be used to access your elements from inside that p-table.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It has usage examples, but the point is I don't want to put those regular markups inside the element. I want to code them somewhere else (outside of it, for some reasons), but I want them somehow to pass/inject/transfer/etc to the `p-table`, so it can use them normally.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] to give some more context - how would you use this? What are you trying to achieve? What precisely happens with your current attempt (give a [mcve])?